# my table seems weird

Tags: tables

In my project documentation I have to use many tables however my tables really seems weird.

I tried this:

```
\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \cline{2-4}
    \multicolumn{}{c|}{} & Application Layer&Transport\&Network Layer&Data Link\&Physical Layer\\
        &Layer 7& Layer 4\&3&Layer 2\&1\\ \hline
    WAN&IEC 62056/COSEM&TCP/IP&IEC 62056/COSEM\\
        &&&PLC G3\\
        &&&
        \begin{center}
        Fibre VLAN
        \end{center}
        \\ \hline
    HAN&ZigBee Smart Energy 1.0/2.0&ZigBee 2.0&ZigBee\\
        &EN 13757-3 M-Bus&EN 50090-4&PLC\\
        &IEC 62056/COSEM&&\\
        &EN 50090-3\\
        &&&EN 13757-2 M-Bus\\
        &&&EN 50090-4\\ \hline
            \end{tabular} 
            \caption{The standardization bodies CEN, CENELEC and ETSI identify smart metering European data exchange and communication standards which are categorized by depending on the network layer model and the network size.}
            \label{table:standards}
   \end{table}
```

It seem like this [image]

Could someone help me? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Yes, this table is weird! `\begin{center}...\end{center}` in a table cell?

Comment: When a table has vertical rules, you have to specify also empty cells. The row ``&EN 50090-3\\`` should be ``&EN 50090-3&&\\``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some `&` missing to provide the vertical lines, as well as the first two rows should omit the '|' most likely.

This code runs now, but I would not really suggest this look of the table.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|*{4}{c|}}
  \cline{2-4}
  \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}     & Application Layer&Transport\&Network Layer&Data Link\&Physical Layer\tabularnewline
   \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}    & Layer 7& Layer 4\&3&Layer 2\&1\tabularnewline 
  \hline
  WAN&IEC 62056/COSEM&TCP/IP&IEC 62056/COSEM\tabularnewline
  &&&PLC G3\tabularnewline
  &&&
  Fibre VLAN
  \tabularnewline \hline
  HAN&ZigBee Smart Energy 1.0/2.0&ZigBee 2.0&ZigBee\tabularnewline
  &EN 13757-3 M-Bus&EN 50090-4& PLC\tabularnewline
  &IEC 62056/COSEM&&\tabularnewline
  &EN 50090-3 & & \tabularnewline
  &&&EN 13757-2 M-Bus\tabularnewline
  &&&EN 50090-4\tabularnewline 
  \hline
\end{tabular} 
\caption[Standardization bodies]{The standardization bodies CEN, CENELEC and ETSI identify smart metering European data exchange and communication standards which are categorized by depending on the network layer model and the network size.}
\label{table:standards}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Than you for your help. Why do not you suggest this look?

Comment: @limonik: It's not nice to read -- a personal opinion, but I am sure, others will frown on the vertical lines and the spacings as well.

Answer (score 0):

If use of additional package is not an obstacle, please consider the folowing code for your table:

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{makecell}% <-- new package

    \usepackage[margin=25mm,showframe]{geometry}% for show page layout

    \begin{document}
    \vspace*{1ex}
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{|*{4}{c|}}
    \cline{2-4}
\multicolumn{1}{c|}{}     
    &   \makecell{Application Layer\\Layer 7}
        &   \makecell{Transport \& Network Layer\\Layer 4 \&3} 
            &   \makecell{Data Link \& Physical Layer\\ Layer 2 \& 1}   
                                                        \tabularnewline
  \hline
WAN &   IEC 62056/COSEM 
        &   TCP/IP  
            &   \makecell[t]{IEC 62056/COSEM\\                
                          PLC G3\\
                          Fibre VLAN}                       \tabularnewline
    \hline
HAN &   \makecell[t]{ZigBee Smart Energy 1.0/2.0\\
                  EN 13757-3 M-Bus \& EN 50090-4\\
                  IEC 62056/COSEM\\
                  EN 50090-3}
        &   \makecell[t]{ZigBee 2.0\\
                      EN 50090-4}                           
            &   \makecell[t]{ZigBee\\
                          PLC}                              \tabularnewline
    &   &   &   \makecell[t]{EN 13757-2 M-Bus\\
                         EN 50090-4}                        \tabularnewline
  \hline
\end{tabular}
    \caption[Standardization bodies]{The standardization bodies CEN, CENELEC and ETSI identify smart metering European data exchange and communication standards which are categorized by depending on the network layer model and the network size.}
\label{table:standards}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

In case, that you like to have bigger distance between `\hline`s and cells content, than after `begin{table}` add

```
\begin{table}[h]
    \centering
\setcellgapes{2pt}% <--
\makegapedcells   % <--
...
```

and table become like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, using `\makecell`, that allows for line breaks in cells, resulting in a simpler code. I loaded the `geometry` package, that has by default more sensible margins than the default (unless you want margin notes). Otherwise, you'd have rto set the font size to `\scriptsize`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{array, makecell, caption}

\begin{document}

\mbox{}\vskip1cm
\begin{table}[h]
\centering\setcellgapes{3pt}\makegapedcells
\captionsetup{format=hang}
\setlength\tabcolsep{3.5pt}%\small
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
        \cline{2-4}
    \multicolumn{1}{c|}{} & \makecell{Application Layer\\Layer 7} & \makecell{Transport \& Network Layer\\Layer 4 \& 3} & \makecell{Data Link \& Physical Layer\\Layer 2 \& 1}\\
    \hline
    WAN & IEC 62056/COSEM & TCP/IP & \makecell{IEC 62056/COSEM\\ PLC G3\\Fibre VLAN}\\
       \hline
    HAN & \makecell{ZigBee Smart Energy 1.0/2.0\\EN 13757-3 M-Bus\\IEC 62056/COSEM\\EN 50090-3} & \makecell{ZigBee 2.0\\EN 50090-4} & \makecell{ZigBee\\PLC\\EN 13757-2 M-Bus\\EN 50090-4}\\
     \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{The standardization bodies CEN, CENELEC and ETSI identify smart metering European data exchange and communication standards which are categorized by depending on the network layer model and the network size.}
    \label{table:standards}
   \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image]